# how to change the Search view in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

how can I change the Eclipse Search view from [image]

to notepad search view like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select the flat view for the result.

From the [help page](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_search_view.htm):

> [image: menu] **Menu**: Lists two selectable view layouts for search results: Flat and Hierarchical.

(introduced in 2004, [with Eclipse3.0](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.0-200406251208/eclipse-news-part5-R3.html))

[image: flat]

Not *exactly* like Notepad++, but close.